# What is the best way to reproduce QLPreviewController functionality in Adobe AIR for mobile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I would like to reproduce the functionality of the QLPreviewController in an AIR mobile app for iOS including the UIDocumentInteractionController that is available when viewing an item in the PreviewController.

Is this possible using an ANE?  Do I have to roll my own implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a microarchitecture framework?  If that's the case then you should check out Swiz, Robotlegs or Mate.